# How to make MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen in landscape and not fullscreen in portrait

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a `MPMoviePlayerController` that is initialized as follows:

```
//Code in my UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *myVideoView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *myVideoPlayer;

- (void) initializeVideoPlayer
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
    self.myVideoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myVideoView];

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    self.myVideoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    self.myVideoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    self.myVideoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.myVideoPlayer.view setFrame: self.myVideoView.bounds];
    [self.myVideoView addSubview: self.myVideoPlayer.view];

    //Play video
    [self.myVideoPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.myVideoPlayer play];

}
```

My question is how do I get the video to play in fullscreen when the user rotates the phone to landscape and not fullscreen when the phone is in portrait.

I've tried adding the following to my `UIViewController`

```
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
        [self.myVideoPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.myVideoPlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

However, the problem with this is that once the player is in fullscreen, the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` no longer gets called; therefore, even when the user rotates back to portrait, the video is still in fullscreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead of an `MPMoviePlayerController`. Just initialize it in your `UIViewController` and use its `moviePlayer` property as you would with a plain `MPMoviePlayerController`. If you subclass `MPMoviePlayerViewController` you can control what's happening when the device rotates by implementing `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.h:

```
@property(nonatomic)BOOL allowRotation;
```

in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    RootViewController * root = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = root;

//add two Notification

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPVisionVideoNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPVisionVideoNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void) moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    self.allowRotation = YES;
}

- (void) moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    self.allowRotation = NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (self.allowRotation) {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight ;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

//this can rotate the windows when to fullscreen state
```